# Open and Load Modal Window w/ Javascript and Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Codeigniter and Datatables together and need to load a modal popup when the user clicks "view" for a certain row of data.

Here is my link with my onClick:

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript:notes_modal()">view</a>
```

Here is my JS:

```
function notes_modal(data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../load_notes_modal",
    }).done(function ( html ) { 
        $("#selected_note").modal('show');
    });
}
```

Here is my view that is being loaded by the "load_notes_modal" function I'm calling:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="selected_note" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        Random Content!
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">View Location Note</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not getting any errors, just no luck getting the modal to show. I'm new to JS and trying to learn, I might be headed in the complete wrong direction!

Comment: check this answer - Hope it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158733/open-a-modal-in-codeigniter-that-loads-in-a-iframe-content-from-an-url-that

Answer (score 1):

You will want to put your modal trigger in the success callback like so:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class=".openModal">view</a>
```

JS

```
function notes_modal() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../load_notes_modal",
        success: function ( html ) { 
            $("#selected_note").modal('show');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('ajax did not succeed');
        }
    });
}

function clickListener() {
    $('.openModal').unbind();
    $('.openModal').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        notes_modal();
    });
}
```

You have your dataTable something like below. Call the functions from within `fnDrawCallback()` so that each time the table is drawn, the listeners are called. Note the changes made above as well.

```
var oTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
    "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
        notes_modal();
        clickListener();
    }
});
```

New Update: To work with dataTable redraw.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It's still not working however... The URL is linking to a function in a controller that is calling the view. Am I missing something there possibly? I checked my JS Console and it's the correct link.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ready' of undefined

Comment: Do you not have jQuery included?

Comment: I do. I've got several other modals being used, but this is the first one being called dynamically so I'm struggling.