# Is there a way to open/fire a modal in the controller? CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to open modal / fire modal in the controller function.

Here is my controller:

```
public function enlist(){
  ....
  <a href="#" onclick="modalLoadAttachments(\'' . $folderPath . '\')" class="btn btn-info" data-controls-modal="viewAttachments" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#viewAttachments"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i> View Attachments</a>
  ....
}
```

View: - The modal html codes are here* Is there a way to open this in the controller?

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="viewAttachments" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header standard-modal-header">                 
                <?php echo $modalHeader; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalAttachmentsBody">                    
                <h4 class="font-blue">Pre-Enrollment Other Information:</h4>
                <ul class="padding-left40">
                    <li><b>Pre Enrollment Date: </b><?php echo date_format(date_create($recordSet->preEnrollmentDate), "F d, Y"); ?></li>
                    <!--<li><b>Bank Reference Number: </b><?php //echo ($recordSet->bankReferenceNumber == '' ? 'NONE' : $recordSet->bankReferenceNumber); ?></li>-->
                    <li><b>Family Average Income: </b><?php echo ($recordSet->averageIncome == '' ? 'NONE' : '₱ ' . $recordSet->averageIncome); ?></li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
                <h4 class="font-blue">Pre-Enrollment File Attachment(s):</h4>
                <p class="text-right">
                    <a href="#" onclick="generateZIP('<?php echo $folderPath; ?>', '<?php echo $studentID; ?>')"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download All</a>
                </p>                   
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">                
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

Comment: does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154312/open-and-load-modal-window-w-javascript-and-codeigniter

Comment: since your code example has a javascript onclick event, you should know about client side scripting. Opening a modal window is a client side action. Just read on how to use Ajax, like this article: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX and many others.